# Using JSON object question

Tags: javascript, json

OK so i have this script that submits the input of a search box to a .php and gives back a JSON object in jquery. How can i now change the content of a div. The JSON object that is returnd looks like this:

```
{"0":"Aardappelen rauw","voedsel":"Aardappelen rauw","1":"88","calorien":"88"}
```

How can i say that 'Aardappelen rauw' should be in div1 and 88 in div 2 for example? I tried with data.voedsel and data.calorien but that doesn't work..

in head:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function contentDisp()
{

$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'getFood.php',
  data: {'foodnametextbox' : $('#food').val() },
  datatype: "json",
  success: function(data){ 

    $('.second').replaceWith(data);

  }
});


}
</script>
```

in body:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner first">Hello</div>
  <div class="inner second">And</div>
  <div class="inner third">Goodbye</div>
</div>
```

Comment: OK problem solved! But now another problem: when I perform the search and update the div it only does it once.. if i change my query and press the button again the DIV change doesn't work anymore, why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `dataType: 'json'` should automatically call `parseJSON`.  Then you should be able to do `data['0']` (or `data.voedsel`) to get 'Aardappelen rauw'.

**EDIT**: Change `datatype: "json"` to `dataType: "json"`.  The 't'  in 'type' needs to be capital.

Comment: @Javaaaa: You're welcome.  It's sometimes hard to spot these stupid little errors.

Comment: oeps wrong edit: But now another problem: when I perform the search and update the div it only does it once.. if i change my query and press the button again the DIV change doesn't work anymore, why is this?

Comment: @Javaaaa: Try changing `$('.second').replaceWith()` to `$('.second').html()`.  `replaceWith` changes the ENTIRE element, `html` just changes the data IN the element.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.parseJSON()` http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/

Comment: No. Change `datatype: 'json'` to `dataType: 'json'`.

Comment: ah yes, thats the mistake, thanks, no need for.parsoJSON() indeed now!

Answer (score 1):

`replaceWith` takes a HTML string, DOM element, or jQuery object. A JSON data object is neither of those. My guess is you want something like this:

```
$('.second').text(data["0"]);
```

EDIT: **Don't use eval**. Your ajax option is wrong. It needs to be `dataType: 'json'`. Note the capital `T`.